# Color detection using Python & OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, colors, color-detection

Is it possible to customize this code in such a way so that it can print something if a specific color is present in a frame or print something else if the color is not detected in the frame? If not, then how can I develop this feature? Any suggestions? I am just a begginer at Computer Vision
and Image Processing. Thank You.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    width = int(cap.get(3))
    height = int(cap.get(4))

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', result)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use region props on your mask:

```py
for region in regionprops(mask):
    # take regions with large enough areas
    if region.area >= 20:
        print("color")
    else:
        print("no color")
```

Something like this should work. I used 20 for the region area but you would have to try what is the best value according to your usage.
This code could even detect how many area of colors are present

Answer (score -1):

The following might work:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    width = int(cap.get(3))
    height = int(cap.get(4))

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # only one colour in range:
    lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 50])
    upper_blue = np.array([90, 50, 50])
    included = False
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
         for j in range(mask.shape[1]):
              if mask[i,j] == 1:
                   included = True

    if included == True:
        print("colour is included")
    else:
        print("colour is not included")
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', result)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You really shouldn't iterate over all pixels with `for` loops like that - it is a massive waste of CPU and time. Try `countNonZero()` instead, or `numpy.count_nonzero()`

Comment: and this would detect any pixel of the given color. I think it's probably best to have a minimum detection area  (well, depending of the OP)

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes that's totally true, I didn't know the countNonZero() function, thank you!

Comment: May I ask you how one can get an account with the right to comment on questions and all that as a beginner in programming? I tried to answer the question as best as I could and of course this isn't perfect but working I guess and I only get downvotes... I'm just waiting for my account to get blocked because of too many downvotes and that stuff :D

Comment: You'll get there... keep practicing, keep reading, keep learning. We were all new once and even with experience we still make mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

You can print colorful like this

```
import os

os.system('')
#Red: \33[31m
#Green: \033[1;32;40m
#Reset color: \033[0;37;40m

print('\033[1;32;40mHello everyone.\033[0;37;40m')
print("\33[31mBrooo this is red and so susy i think.\033[0;37;40m\n")
```

Comment: I think you have maybe mis-read the question. It is about looking for colours in a video stream with OpenCV.